# Projecting domain model child count onto view model without extra queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Assume I'm using the following Entity Framework entities:

```
public class Country : DomainObject<int>
{
    private ICollection<StateOrProvince> _statesOrProvinces;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StateOrProvince> StatesOrProvinces
    {
        get { return _statesOrProvinces ?? (_statesOrProvinces = new List<StateOrProvince>()); }
        protected set { _statesOrProvinces = value; }
    }
}

public class StateOrProvince : DomainObject<int>
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

I want to project onto the following view model for my presentation layer:

```
public class CountryListModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "States/Provinces")]
    public int StatesOrProvincesCount { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I have a **StateOrProvincesCount** property on my model that is supposed to represent an aggregate count of the **StatesOrProvinces** list on my Country entity.

In order to keep my MVC controller code lean, I created static mapping extension methods for my domain entities. The one for mapping to the *CountryListModel* looks like this:

```
public static CountryListModel MapToListModel(this Country country) 
{
    return new CountryListModel 
    { 
        Id = country.Id, 
        Name = country.Name, 
        Abbreviation = country.Abbreviation, 
        StatesOrProvincesCount = country.StatesOrProvinces.Count
    };
 }
```

I then attempted to use it as follows:

```
var models = _countries.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.MapToListModel()).ToList();
```

However, this threw the exception **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'CountryListModel MapToListModel(Country)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.** My assumption was that this was an issue with `IQueryable` being unable to convert the code to SQL.

So then I tried:

```
var models = _countries.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.MapToListModel()).ToList();
```

This did not throw an error and gave me the results I wanted. However, when viewing SQL Express Profiler I can see that this results in **(N+1)** queries being sent to the database. First it queries to get the list of countries, then queries to select all of the States/Provinces for each country.

If you throw out the mapping extension and project directly within the `.Select` method there is only one query and it performs the `Count` directly in the SQL instead of returning the States/Provinces then counting those:

```
var models = _countries.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new CountryListModel 
{ 
    Id = x.Id, 
    Name = x.Name, 
    Abbreviation = x.Abbreviation, 
    StatesOrProvincesCount = x.StatesOrProvinces.Count 
}).ToList();
```

That is fantastic, however this is just a quick prototype. In the long run I want to separate things into layers (e.g. - Core, Data, Business, Presentation).

From what I've learned during this process, it appears that the View Model I'm projecting on will have to be known by the Data layer in order to query efficiently. In cases such as this do the View Models belong in the Core/Common project along with the Domain entities? Should I create additional DTO objects and map onto those? How do you handle this in your projects?

Comment: `MapToListModel()` does not exist in SQL Server so it has NO idea what you want. Have you tried: `_countries.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList().Select(x => x.MapToListModel()).ToList();` You're also asking some conceptual questions about programming that would be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com regarding Core/Data/Business/Presentation.

Comment: you can use https://automapper.codeplex.com/ (AutoMapper) to map between Domain object and ViewModels ... it's just a configuration layer to be added to your project

Comment: Erik, that would work, but would result in **N+1** queries just like my other example. Sherif, I'm aware of AutoMapper but fail to see how it addresses the aggregate **N+1** query issue.  Linq to SQL doesn't know about AutoMapper any more than it knows about the extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your solution is wrong. I have used it before and sometimes ended up writing my own SQL and passed to EF. It is much easier sometimes than trying to flex EF to create the one you want. In this case, EF simply can't do much about your extension method. For the solutions mentioned in the comments, you are hitting N+1 because of `country.StatesOrProvinces.Count` in the extension method. If you can't flatten that then writing your SQL could be a good option.

> In the long run I want to separate things into layers (e.g. - Core, Data, Business, Presentation).

I have tried to achieve this several times in past projects, used Repositories of all kinds, UnitOfWorks, ViewModels,etc. The result was not quite satisfactory. It often resulted in bloated data access layers and service layers violating single responsibility principle everywhere, adding more maintenance headaches.This [post](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) by Rob Conery made me think differently. Staying simple is more important than dogmatic optimizations you don't need. Both discussed solutions,Command/Query Objects (Not necessarily full CQRS) and Using DataContext for the life of the request work well and grow nicely with the life of the project.

> In cases such as this do the View Models belong in the Core/Common project along with the Domain entities? Should I create additional DTO objects and map onto those? How do you handle this in your projects?

I highly recommend taking a look at Jimmy Bogard's take on [Contoso University App](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity/tree/master/src/ContosoUniversity). He is using [MediatoR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR). It is very well decoupled. It is worth a shot.

There is no silver bullet. Before starting to tighten the code, the things I'd keep in mind are simplicity, testability and performance. There is always a temptation of putting "common code" in some place accessed by several things. I'd think of a reason for change before creating such entities.

I hope this helps.