# Entity Framework ObjectContext lifetime in an n-tier project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, n-tier-architecture

I'm currently building a large solution for a client where code reuseability is the keyword since different types of projects (i.e. Websites, WCF services, WPF etc) should use the exact same businesslogic.

Right now, my solution looks like this:

- Businesslogic layer (all of the logic that defines business rules is added here)
- Interfaces
- Model (ViewModels, DTOs etc)
- Repository (currently using Entity Framework 6. This is where all database transactions go)
- Webservices (WCF services)
- MVC website

The point is that any presentation layer (i.e. the MVC website) will use the businesslogic layer which then uses the repository to make any database transaction needed.

While this works the way I want to, I find myself constantly battleing the ObjectContext from the Entity Framework, simply because, when querying for data in the repository, the entities doesn't get transferred to the businesslogic (which is logical because of EFs lazy-loading) I'm aware that I can make use of the `.Include(x => x.MyOtherTable)`, but since the database is fairly large, this approach gets bloated quickly and queries can be rather large if the included table has a lot of records.

I've then made a `DbContextManager` class which looks like this:

```
public static class DbContextManager
{
    //Unique context key per request and thread
    private static string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("MyDb_{0}{1}", HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x"), Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID);
        }
    }

    //Get and set request context
    private static MyEntities Context
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Items[Key] as MyEntities ; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items[Key] = value; }
    }

    //Context per request
    public static MyEntities Current
    {
        get
        {
            //if null, create new context 
            if (Context == null)
            {
                Context = new MyEntities ();
                HttpContext.Current.Items[Key] = Context;
            }
            return Context;
        }
    }

    //Dispose any created context at the end of a request - called from Global.asax
    public static void Dispose()
    {
        if (Context != null)
        {
            Context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my global.asax, I'm disposing the context when a request is ended:

```
private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbContextManager.Dispose();
    }
```

This works perfect, I can now make my initial database call in the repository and then make the businesslogic rules in my businesslogic layer, simply because the ObjectContext lives for the http request.

However, when I need to call the same businesslogic methods from the WCF services project (or i.e. a WPF project), I won't be able to make use of my DbContextManager class since it relies on the HttpContext.

I feel I'm doing this completely wrong at the moment and I'm fighting an unnessecary battle with the Entity Framework. What have I missed? Is Entity Framework the right ORM for these types of solutions? It certainly doesn't feel like that right now :-)

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is truly horrifying to see your database context get disposed in the service layer.  Why don't you simply explicitly load your entities in your DAL, rather than bubbling up deferred queries?  Perhaps more targeted, smaller services will help alleviate the bloat and help you avoid needing to bubble your database straight to the top.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your input. "Horrifing", that's a big word ;-) in my service layer? I'm not sure what you mean. It gets disposed in the MVC application when a request has ended. No service layer involved there in my eyes. Is it possible for you to make a code snippet of "explicit loading of entities" ? I'm not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637516/projecting-domain-model-child-count-onto-view-model-without-extra-queries/29639310#296393100] It may give you some ideas.

Comment: @BoMortensen My apologies for the confusion.  My problem with disposing the db context in your global asax is that you've completely tied your database to your web project (MVC).  There is no separation of concerns and no inversion of control.  To me, this is a pretty horrifying spot to be in a n-tier application.  As for explicitly loading your entities, anytime you resolve your query with ToList, ToArray, etc, you are explicitly loading your queried entities into memory.  This allows you to neatly dispose of your context before leaving the DAL.

Comment: David: no worries :-) I definitely see what you mean in regards to the global.asax file. That's exactly my problem: it's too tightly coupled with the DAL like that. I have to tinker a bit with eager loading then, hopefully it will make more sense ;-)

Comment: @Yogiraj: I'm one for simplicity aswell, but this particular project needs the separation of concerns (separated BLL) It's the heart of the business, really :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused here.  It looks like you are using your entity layer objects directly in your view layer.

This is generally a bad idea.  Your model should encapsulate these.  Your business logic layer should use your model layer to build ViewModel and DTO objects, which the UI layer can produce/consume.   This will allow you to fully separate your UI layer from your database/entity layer.

That will make re-using your business logic in a web service layer trivial.  It should know nothing of your database layer.  Otherwise adding or changing a field in your entity layer will have a direct impact on all the UI layers.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your input. You are right, I've actually made some DTOs which are mapped from the entities now. Works better than using the entities directly. I'm a bit unsure as to **where** I should map the entities to DTOs: in the repository classes or in the business logic layer? What would you go with? :-)

Comment: I usually do this in the business layer.   If you do it at the repository layer, you end up with another mapping layer between business logic and view layer.  Some people really want this level of decoupling, theorizing that they would want to make database layer changes without changing business logic, but that rarely pays off (IMHO).  I have built systems that map at both layers, and it usually ended up feeling like wasted time/energy, and adding a lot more mapping code that can go awry.

Comment: Another nice side-effect of putting in the DTO layer is that you can more easily support things like backwards compatibility.  Not exposing your entities to your UI means that you can do things like add additional fields with intelligent defaults.  This will make your business logic layer MUCH more resilient over time.